# Escaping special characters in bash variables

Tags: bash, escaping, special-characters, scp

I'm trying to read a file containing filepaths line by line and scp the files to another server, but because of certain characters in the filenames like '(', ')', '&' etc. I need to escape the input:

**input.txt**:

```
/folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses)
```

**script.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

promote_to=random.server.com
dev_catalog=/folderX/
uat_catalog=/folderY/

while read line
do
uat_path=$(echo "$uat_catalog$line" | sed -e "s/(/\\\(/g" | sed -e "s/)/\\\)/g")
dev_path=$(echo "$dev_catalog$line" | sed -e "s/(/\\\(/g" | sed -e "s/)/\\\)/g")

scp $dev_path user@$promote_to:$uat_path
scp $dev_path".atr" user@$promote_to:$uat_path".atr"
done < "input.txt"
```

**Output**:

```
-bash: /folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses): No such file or directory
-bash: /folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses): No such file or directory
usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
               [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
               [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2
ssh: random.server.com: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that the local and remote filenames are parsed differently: the local filename is used directly, so the only thing you need to do is enclose it in double-quotes (as in @Ignacio's answer), but the remote filename gets passed to a remote shell which runs it through another layer of parsing (quote and escape removal, etc).  So, you want to add escapes to the remote path *only*.  I've also taken the liberty of simplifying the `sed` command a little:

```
#!/bin/sh

promote_to=random.server.com
dev_catalog=/folderX/
uat_catalog=/folderY/

while read line
do
uat_path="$(echo "$uat_catalog$line" | sed -e 's/[()&]/\\&/g')"
dev_path="$dev_catalog$line"

scp "$dev_path" "user@$promote_to:$uat_path"
scp "$dev_path.atr" "user@$promote_to:$uat_path.atr"
done < "input.txt"
```

Note that the `sed` pattern I used, `'s/[()&]/\\&/g'`, only escapes parentheses and ampersands; if your filenames contain any other shell metacharacters, be sure to add them to the character list in `[]`.

Comment: For those wondering on how to escape single quotes, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9746/how-to-replace-quotation-marks-in-a-file-with-sed

Answer (score 2):

The other way around would be to NOT escape special chars but to quote the value in a format that can be re-used as an input instead (modern Bash is implied, e.g. version 5 and higher):

```
> VAR='/folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses)'
> echo $VAR
/folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses)
> echo ${VAR@Q}
'/folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute `/folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses)` as a command. You probably meant to do `echo /folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses) | ...` instead.

Edit: what @Ignacio said.

Comment: that's right... missed the echo, but still doesn't work: "/folder1/folderA/filename+\\(oh+how+nice,+parantheses\\): No such file or directory"

Comment: removing one backslash from each sed throws this however: "bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `scp -t bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `scp -t /folder1/folderA/filename+(oh+how+nice,+parantheses)'
lost connection"