# escape symbols in bash variable from secret_key

Tags: bash, shell, sed, escaping

I am trying to use the following commands to replace in file.

```sh
export SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
    
grep -q '^SECRET_KEY' .env &&
sed -i 's|^SECRET_KEY.*|SECRET_KEY='"$SECRET_KEY"'|' .env ||
echo 'SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}' >> .env
```

However, when I start, I get an error

```
bash: -c: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

I think this is due to the fact that there are special characters in the variable **$SECRET_KEY**.
This in *sample* content:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'r6mslqw$4md09)r5k(3d%jy32j18&3ceazl**6io=n0*w6502$'
```

It is a secret key from django to replace in `.env` from github. How to escape all these symbols correctly? I've read [Escaping special characters in bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483171/escaping-special-characters-in-bash-variables) this topic but I didn't quite understand it

I found this function from django source code https://github.com/django/django/blob/bf7afe9c4e21f5fe5090c47b2b6ffc5a03a85815/django/core/management/utils.py#L77:

```
def get_random_secret_key():
    """
    Return a 50 character random string usable as a SECRET_KEY setting value.
    """
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
    return get_random_string(50, chars)
```

so all of these characters are valid and must be escaped

Comment: Your example does not have 22 lines and none of them contain `)` so the error message is not from this example. Some of your syntax looks like this is being run by Jenkins or Github Actions or something; probably [edit] to explain these details, or remove the irrrelevant details and provide a proper [mre]

Comment: `export SECRET_KEY='${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}'` with single quotes around the value will prevent the shell from attempting to interpret the string. This could still break if the string contains literal single quotes.

Comment: Wrapping the secret key in single-quotes will work unless the password contains a single-quote, in which case it will break horribly. If the password *might* contain a single-quote, you'll have to do something more elaborate.

Comment: single qoutes works, thanks @tripleee